# Open gem, using Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, rubymine

How can I open gem for editing in Rubymine? I use this command `bundle open gem_name`, but got this error: `To open a bundled gem, set $EDITOR or $BUNDLER_EDITOR`

So I need to locate, where my Rubymine is installed and then add $EDITOR variable. How can I do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

In rubymine, run `Tools -> Create command-line launcher`. This will create a small script called `mine` (or `rubymine`) in your `/usr/local/bin`.

Now that it is in the `$PATH`, you can simply do

```
export EDITOR=mine
```

(add this to your `~/.bashrc` or whatever shell init script you use)

Comment: Have done everything, but it happens nothing when I run `bundle open gem_name`. Looks like rubymine is not launching

Comment: what does `which mine` say?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/mine`

Comment: And if you say `mine .`, does it open rubymine?

Comment: No. Can it be connected with rubymine was installed using jetbrains-toolbox?

Comment: @Headmaster: I don't think so. I have the same setup, only I'm on macos (which should not make difference in this context)